# Unable to run reactjs in ubuntu server - getting error process out of memory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have installed node and npm and added the required packages and codes in my ubuntu 16.04 server to run my react js app but, gives the following error. Anyone know what will be the reason?

My nodejs version : 9.6.1,
npm version : 5.6.0

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[19568:0x38d48f0]    26167 ms: Scavenge 125.9 (251.3) -> 116.8 (251.3) MB, 21.0                                                                                         
/ 0.0 ms  allocation failure
[19568:0x38d48f0]    26296 ms: Scavenge 129.3 (251.3) -> 119.4 (251.3) MB, 22.9                                                                                         
/ 0.0 ms  allocation failure
[19568:0x38d48f0]    26627 ms: Scavenge 154.6 (267.0) -> 143.6 (267.0) MB, 31.3                                                                                         
/ 1.6 ms  allocation failure
[19568:0x38d48f0]    27161 ms: Scavenge 157.7 (268.8) -> 150.5 (268.8) MB, 26.2                                                                                         
/ 3.9 ms  allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->
Cannot get stack trace in GC.
FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x8cae0c [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xa38f8b [node]
 6: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::Evacuate() [node]
 7: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::CollectGarbage() [node]
 8: v8::internal::Heap::MarkCompact() [node]
 9: v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector,                                                                                         v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
10: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::intern                                                                                        al::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
11: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag)                                                                                         [node]
12: v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ConsStr                                                                                        ing>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
13: v8::internal::JsonStringifier::SerializeString(v8::internal::Handle<v8::inte                                                                                        rnal::String>) [node]
14: v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Seriali                                                                                        ze_<false>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handl                                                                                        e<v8::internal::Object>) [node]
15: v8::internal::JsonStringifier::SerializeArrayLikeSlow(v8::internal::Handle<v                                                                                        8::internal::JSReceiver>, unsigned int, unsigned int) [node]
16: v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Seriali                                                                                        ze_<true>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle                                                                                        <v8::internal::Object>) [node]
17: v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Seriali                                                                                        ze_<false>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handl                                                                                        e<v8::internal::Object>) [node]
18: v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Stringify(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::                                                                                        Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::in                                                                                        ternal::Object>) [node]
19: v8::internal::Builtin_JsonStringify(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::interna                                                                                        l::Isolate*) [node]
20: 0x15edd1e8697d
The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the s                                                                                        ystem ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! admin-react@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the admin-react@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log                                                                                        ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/abouttrees/.npm/_logs/2018-03-05T06_21_18_949Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I believe npm requires 1GB of RAM. Does your server have this?

Comment: OK. Thanks Steve